# jQuery not fires 'focusout' after .appendTo() in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

jQuery not fires 'focusout' after .appendTo() call in IE.

```
$("input[type=text]").on("focusin", function() { $(this).css("border-color", "red"); });
$("input[type=text]").on("focusout", function() { $(this).css("border-color", "lightgray"); });

var $content = $("#content");
var $containerBlue = $("#container-blue");
var $containerGreen = $("#container-green");

$("#trigger-btn").on("mousedown", function() {
  if($containerBlue.find("#content").length > 0)
    $content.appendTo($containerGreen);
  else
    $content.appendTo($containerBlue);
});
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/KhD/emzrhnuy/3/

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click any input - it gets red border
2. Click the 'Trigger' button -
   the container with the inputs will be appended from one div to
   another
3. The red border is gone in Chrome, but remains in IE.

Is there a way to overcome this without using setTimeout() ?

Comment: Did you try with blur event.

Comment: Why don't you just use CSS for that???  `input[type=text]:focus {
  border-color: red;
}`    https://jsfiddle.net/emzrhnuy/4/

Comment: In my project I need to bind more complex eventHandlers (that change not only the 'border-color' val) so CSS is not applicable

Comment: Using 'blur' instead doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @IlyaKhD But you can still trigger it or easier, bind click event, not mousedown   https://jsfiddle.net/emzrhnuy/5/ **&&** https://jsfiddle.net/emzrhnuy/7/

Comment: @A. Wolff Unfortunately it has to be 'mousedown', not 'click' or 'mouseup' or smth like

Comment: @IlyaKhD You have many contraints... So like said, trigger the event on mousedown: `$("input[type=text]:focus").trigger('focusout');`  And for styling, use CSS

Comment: Of course I style this with CSS, I use border-color in the sample just to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @A. Wolff the jsfiddle#7 you provided does not work in IE (border remains being red), the #5 behaves in a proper way but  I would like to find a solution\explanation for jQuery failure to fire 'focusout' in this very circumstances and without such workarounds as 'find all the inputs and fire this event manually'

Comment: @A. Wolff, anyway, thank you for the options you provided!

Comment: @IlyaKhD #7 works for me on IE11. That's said, issue has nothing to do with jQuery but how each browser implement event stake. IE, nor FF fire event on detached element. It surprisingly works on chrome. Now try setting explicitely focus on button on mousedown before detaching input from DOM https://jsfiddle.net/emzrhnuy/8/  (works for me on FF/IE/chrome)

Comment: Sorry: *IE, or FF, **doesn't** fire event*

Comment: I'm sorry for not pointing out one more constraint - this must work for 'mousedown' fired not only on input, but also on the 'body' element, which is unable to be focused J

Comment: Any element can be focusable https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute Set tabindex attribute. But looks like completly unrelevant to your opening question. So what else?!....

Comment: @A. Wolff Thank you for your answers it helped me to overcome the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround is to trigger focus event manually i.e. one can additionally set focus on any aproprate element, so to say 'focus stealer':

```
$("#focus-stealer").focus();
```

Note that the using document element as a 'focus-stealer' can have some issues in IE. And document.activeElement should be checked for being undefined.

You can also use this:

```
document.activeElement.blur();
```

To make this more specifc one can use smth like

```
if($("#container").find(":focus").length > 1)
    document.activeElement && document.activeElement.blur();
```